# c++ . Extract the 3rd word of a array and print its Ascii code along with character value

Tags: c++, arrays, string, extract

I wrote a program to extract 3rd word from a string(of 3 words) and print 
If string is "God Is One"
o/p - One-79-110-101 
i want to make it more generalize by making it nth word of a string

```
       #include<iostream.h>
       #include<conio.h>
       #include<stdio.h>
       #include<ctype.h>
       void main ()
       {           
       int i,j,k,x;
       clrscr();
       char a[20];
       cout<<"enter a string";
       gets(a);
       for(i=0;a[i]!='\0';i++)
           {
             if(a[i]==' ')
              {
                for(j=i+1;a[j]!='\0';j++)
                    {
                         if(a[j]==' ')
                            {           
                                    x=j;
                            }
                    }
              }
           }
               for(i=x+1;a[i]!='\0';i++)
                {
                   cout<<a[i];
                }
                for(i=x+1;a[i]!='\0';i++)
                {
                  k =int(a[i]);
                  cout<<"-"<<k;
                }
       getch();
       }
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Oh no. He used `gets`. The world is about to end.

Comment: A lot of this code can be cleaned up using C++...

Comment: i want to make it nth term 
sir i m a beginner  , so yes world is just beginning for me . what should i have used ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, in C it's probably easiest to extract a word using `scanf` with the `%s` conversion (though with it, you *always* want to specify a maximum length, like `%63s` if you're reading into a 64-byte buffer) . Likewise, in C++ it's probably easiest with the string extraction operator `>>`.

So, the easiest way in C++ would probably be something like:

```
std::string word;
for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
    std::cin >> word;
```

This simply reads N words from standard input into the same string. Each of the first N-1 words is simply overwritten by the next word you extract, so when you're done you have the N<sup>th</sup> word stored in `word`.

Note that there are other ways to do this job, some of which have advantages under some circumstances -- but for now, this is probably fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is another way it could be done. This example includes some error handling.

gcc 4.7.3: g++ -Wall -Wextra nth-word.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <string>

int main() {
  int n;
  while((std::cout << "Enter a number: ") && !(std::cin >> n)) {
    // Erroneous input. Clear the fail state and flush the input buffer.
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
  }

  std::string s;
  std::cout << "Enter a string: ";

  // Read n words.
  while ((std::cin >> s) && (0 < --n));

  // Throw away the rest of the stream.
  std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

  // Required output.    
  std::cout << s;
  for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i) {
    std::cout << '-' << static_cast<int>(s[i]);
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;

  // Wait for more input before exiting.
  std::cin.ignore();

  return 0;
}
```

Example session.

```
Enter a number: text
Enter a number: 4
Enter a string: mary had a little lamb
little-108-105-116-116-108-101
```